# Number of keys in a Java Keystore

Tags: hadoop, keystore

We are using Hadoop KMS which internally uses Java keystore to store the various keys. Keystore maintains keys from multiple Hadoop clusters. We now need to migrate the keys from the present instance to multiple other stores, essentially splitting keys per cluster.

Wondering what is the best way to achieve this.

1. Is there a way to understand the number of keys in a store?
2. What is the best mechanism to export keys from a store?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your solution if found.